# Spacing in Navigation Menu (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, spacing

```
.body-color {
    background: rgb(27,39,57)
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    padding-right: 20px;

}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 30px;
}   

#menu {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

I have tried to padding/margins in both the anchor and li but nothing happens.
How do I add spacing in between each menu option?

---

[image]

My HTML, am I assigning it to the wrong place?:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body class="body-color">
<h1 class="logo"><h1>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portrait</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product Showcase</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML, too. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should add your HTML code to identify the elements where you are applying the tags and selectors

Comment: Your code [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/64qc5ego/). Maybe there's something in `reset.css` that overwrites your styles? Also, the closing `<h1>` tag is missing its slash: `</h1>`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't targetting edge or IE, display: flex is a better way of doing what you're doing.

```
#menu {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Would result in each list item being evenly spaced. For practicing basic css skills using flex, I would take a look at [this website](http://flexboxfroggy.com/). They have a lot of great tutorials for basic flex usage.

Comment: Sadly, this did not extend the space in between each navigational option (Menu, Portrait. Product Showcase, Contact).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? you don't have to give width but will manage equal width for each element.

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; /* the magic dust that ensures equal width */
    background: #ccc
}
ul > li {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    text-align: center
}
ul > li > a {
    display:block;
    padding:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer Solved. Followed

```css
.body-color {
    background: rgb(27,39,57)
}
#menu {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}  

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;

}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portrait</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Showcase</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to differ fundamentally from your original code. What was the problem and what did you change to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .body-color {
      background: rgb(27,39,57)
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: .3s;
    }   
    #menu {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: white;
      padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    #menu ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    } 
    #menu ul li + li {
      margin-left: 30px;
    }
    #menu ul li a {
      color: #000;
    } 
    #menu ul li a:hover {
      color: #f10;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
        <title>My Website</title>
      </head>
      <body class="body-color">
        <h1 class="logo"></h1>
        <div id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portrait</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product Showcase</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to support IE 9 or lower. I recommand flex:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly; /* 'space-around' for just filled space */
  width: 100%;
  
  /* list nav normalization */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  /* Additional Options */
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center; 
  
  /* For clarity in this example, remove this when your done */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
#menu li {
  display: inherit;
  /* For clarity in this example, remove this when your done */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
#menu a { 
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  
  /* For clarity in this example, remove this when your done */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portrait</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product Showcase</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that adding `display: inline-block;` to the menu item might work.

Answer (score -1):

Check this link, you can add padding to any direction.

https://codepen.io/jackstride/pen/JLpPgZ

```
li a { padding: 50px;
```

}